# Does Google Chrome ARC work for Adobe Air based Android apps?

Tags: android, google-chrome, air

Google released an [App Runtime for Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc) (Beta), called ARC, that lets you run your favorite Android apps on Chrome OS.
Does ARC supports Android apps that got created with Adobe Air?

Comment: I just tried it and it works (loads and shows app) but it's not representing cpu/gpu graphics quality for vector properly.  I'm testing with basic vector animation and the ARC is showing the app like it's on GPU when it should be on CPU.  This may be correctable but it's not working by default.

Comment: Awesome news, thanks for testing! `GPU when it should be on CPU.` Maybe you can set the *<renderMode>* in the app.xml to _auto_ or _direct_ to fix that issue?

Comment: Changing renderMode affects it but doesn't fix it.  The vectors are aliased.  The animation seems to run fast enough but it's all aliased.

Comment: @moot Just tried it and the app installation silently fails. (Windows 8) What AIR for Android version and settings did you use?

Comment: I'm still on air 16 but you have to keep your AIR up to date.  Does your app work on the device?

Comment: Yes, it works on Android devices. In ARC it loads for a minute and then nothing. (waited 30 min)

Comment: Do a hello world app - nothing in it.  What are using to make it?  Flash?